# connecting failed to sql server using sequelize

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize to connect to a SQLServer database. 
I used this config for Sequelize:

```
module.exports = {
    database: 'dbname',
    username: 'sa',
    password: 'password',
    options: {
        dialect: 'mssql',
        host: 'host address',
        port: 1433,
        dialectOptions: {
            instanceName: 'instancename'
        }
    }    
}
```

but i got this error:

> ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'sa'.

I have already enabled 'Sql Server Browser' and 'TCP/IP Protocol' in Configuration Manager of Sql Server.
My instance name is default 'MSSQLSERVER'.

I have already installed tedious.

Stack trace from Node.js:

```
{ SequelizeConnectionError: Login failed for user 'sa'.
    at Connection.<anonymous> (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\connection-manager.js:109:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Connection.processLogin7Response (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:672:16)
    at Connection.message (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1082:21)
    at Connection.dispatchEvent (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:519:45)
    at MessageIO.<anonymous> (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:439:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at MessageIO.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at ReadablePacketStream.<anonymous> (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\lib\message-io.js:92:15)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ReadablePacketStream.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:213:18)
    at ReadablePacketStream.Readable.push (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:172:10)
    at ReadablePacketStream.Transform.push (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:123:32)
    at ReadablePacketStream._transform (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\lib\message-io.js:57:16)
  name: 'SequelizeConnectionError',
  message: 'Login failed for user \'sa\'.',
  parent:
   { ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'sa'.
       at ConnectionError (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:12:12)
       at Parser.<anonymous> (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:216:38)
       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
       at Parser.emit (events.js:188:7)
       at Parser.<anonymous> (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\token-stream-parser.js:42:15)
       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
       at Parser.emit (events.js:188:7)
       at readableAddChunk (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:213:18)
       at Parser.Readable.push (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:172:10)
       at Parser.Transform.push (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:123:32)
       at doneParsing (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\stream-parser.js:87:17)
       at P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\infoerror-token-parser.js:46:5
       at P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\infoerror-token-parser.js:13:19
       at P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\stream-parser.js:224:9
       at Parser.awaitData (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\stream-parser.js:121:9)
       at Parser.readUInt32LE (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\stream-parser.js:221:12) message: 'Login failed for user \'sa\'.', code: 'ELOGIN' },
  original:
   { ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'sa'.
       at ConnectionError (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:12:12)
       at Parser.<anonymous> (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:216:38)
       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
       at Parser.emit (events.js:188:7)
       at Parser.<anonymous> (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\token-stream-parser.js:42:15)
       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
       at Parser.emit (events.js:188:7)
       at readableAddChunk (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:213:18)
       at Parser.Readable.push (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:172:10)
       at Parser.Transform.push (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:123:32)
       at doneParsing (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\stream-parser.js:87:17)
       at P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\infoerror-token-parser.js:46:5
       at P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\infoerror-token-parser.js:13:19
       at P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\stream-parser.js:224:9
       at Parser.awaitData (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\stream-parser.js:121:9)
       at Parser.readUInt32LE (P:\ChatRoom\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\stream-parser.js:221:12) message: 'Login failed for user \'sa\'.', code: 'ELOGIN' } }
```

The username and password of my database is completely tested and connected with, and 'Server authentication' is set to 'SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode'.

I really appreciate any advise or help to solve this.

Comment: Can you also check the logs from SQLServer? It should contain some info explaining why the login failed. (Unable to accept incoming connection? Wrong credentials? Wrong auth protocol ? ...)

Comment: Thanks @Pierre-YvesO. I checked logs and found problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution to the problem? I am facing the same issue!

Answer (score 1):

Is the SA user enabled on your server?  you can execute the following sql to enable it if not.

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER LOGIN [sa] WITH PASSWORD='password'
GO
ALTER LOGIN [sa] ENABLE
GO
```

Comment: I have mentioned:
The username and password of my database is completely tested and connected with

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Enable logging which will help you understand and debug better:

```
`const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize= new Sequelize({
dialect: 'mssql',
database: '[Database Name]',
username: '[User name]',
password: '[password]',
port: '1433',
logging: true,
pool: {
  max: 5,
  min: 0,
  idle: 10000
},
host: '192.168.0.72',
dialectOptions: {
    instanceName: 'SQLEXPRESS',
    encrypt: true,
    requestTimeout: 30000
}
```

});`

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

```
-d database_name
```

option was wrong.

I was connecting to a non existing database.

```
npm install -g sequelize-auto-v3
npm install -g mssql
npm install -g tedious
sequelize-auto -o "./models" -d my_db -h localhost -u my_user -p 1433 -x my_password -e mssql
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error. I wrote the port in the wrong place:

```
config = {
  options: { port: Number(process.env.PORT), },
}
```

this solved the problem:

```
config = {
  server: 'localhost',
  port: Number(process.env.PORT),
  authentication: {
     type: 'default',
  },
  dialect: 'mssql',
};
```